# How to calculate quantile function for Birnbaum–Saunders distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, quantile-function

[According to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birnbaum%E2%80%93Saunders_distribution) the quantile function of for Birnbaum–Saunders distribution, $ G(p)$, depends on the quantile function of the standard normal distribution.
For example, in the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.06730.pdf it comes "evidently" on page 8, but I don't understand clear why it is almost the same as equation for $T$. How it was found?

Comment: Please post self contained questions, so users don't need to chase links, e.g., to the pdf.  Quote the section of concern on page 8, directly by typing the text into the question field.

Answer (score 2):

I use the notation in the paper you've linked (in case the link in the question dies, it is *Birnbaum-Saunders Distribution: A Review
of Models, Analysis and Applications* by N. Balakrishnan and Debasis Kundu).

We have that if $T \sim \text{BS}(\alpha, \beta)$ that
$$F_{T}(t) = \Phi\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\left\{\left(\dfrac{t}{\beta}\right)^{1/2} - \left(\dfrac{\beta}{t}\right)^{1/2}  \right\}\right]\text{, } \quad t > 0\text{, } \alpha > 0\text{, } \beta > 0\text{.}$$
The $q$th quantile, by definition, is the value $t_q$ (which we assume is $>0$) satisfying
$$F_{T}(t_q) = \Phi\left[\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\left\{\left(\dfrac{t_q}{\beta}\right)^{1/2} - \left(\dfrac{\beta}{t_q}\right)^{1/2}  \right\}\right] = q\text{.}$$
As $\Phi$ is invertible, we obtain
$$\dfrac{1}{\alpha}\left\{\left(\dfrac{t_q}{\beta}\right)^{1/2} - \left(\dfrac{\beta}{t_q}\right)^{1/2}  \right\} = \Phi^{-1}(q) := z_q \tag{1}$$
because $\Phi^{-1}(q)$ is the $q$th quantile of a standard normal random variable. To make the algebra easier, we first observe that
$$\left(\dfrac{t_q}{\beta}\right)^{1/2} - \left(\dfrac{\beta}{t_q}\right)^{1/2} = \dfrac{t_q^{1/2}}{\beta^{1/2}} - \dfrac{\beta^{1/2}}{t_q^{1/2}} = \dfrac{t_q - \beta}{t_q^{1/2}\beta^{1/2}} = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\beta}}\left(\dfrac{t_q - \beta}{\sqrt{t_q}}\right)\text{.}$$
From $(1)$ and our work above, we obtain that
$$\alpha \sqrt{\beta} z_q = \dfrac{t_q - \beta}{\sqrt{t_q}} \implies t_q - \alpha\sqrt{\beta}z_q\sqrt{t_q} - \beta  = 0\text{.}$$
Let $u = \sqrt{t_q}$, then we have the quadratic
$$u^2 - \alpha\sqrt{\beta}z_qu - \beta = 0\text{.}$$
It follows from the quadratic formula that
$$\begin{align}
u &= \sqrt{t_q} \\
&= \dfrac{\alpha\sqrt{\beta}z_q \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2\beta z_q^2 - 4(1)(-\beta)}}{2} \\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta}}{2}\left(\alpha z_q \pm \sqrt{\alpha^2 z_q^2 + 4} \right)  \\
&= \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta}}{2}\left(\alpha z_q \pm \sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2 + 4} \right)\text{.}
\end{align}$$
Now we observe that
$$\sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2 + 4} > \sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2} = \alpha |z_q| \geq \alpha z_q$$
hence
$$ \alpha z_q - \sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2 + 4} < 0$$
so, with the condition that $\sqrt{t_q} \geq 0$, we obtain the unique solution
$$\sqrt{t_q} = \dfrac{\sqrt{\beta}}{2}\left(\alpha z_q + \sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2 + 4} \right)$$
or
$$t_q = \dfrac{\beta}{4}\left(\alpha z_q + \sqrt{(\alpha z_q)^2 + 4} \right)^2$$
This matches equation $(8)$ in the paper.